# how Searching the database for similar numbers?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the way to search the database (mysql/php code) for the following entries:

- 123XX
- 123XY
- XYZ44
- 1X344
- 1Z344
- Z23YY

- The input letters are only X - Y - Z and the numbers from 0 to 9

They are all one number, which is (**12344**), so how can I show these results? The goal is to search for repeated entries.

**Another example :**

12XYY

X = 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

Y = 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

*Provided that y is not equal to x or any apparent number (1,2)*

*And X is not equal to Y or any apparent number (1,2)*

```
$number = "1XZYY";
$rnumber = str_replace(array('Y','X','Z'), "ـ", $number);
$lenNumber = strlen(5);
```

```
$duplicate = $mysqli->query("SELECT `number` FROM `listNumber` WHERE (length(`number`) = '$lenNumber' && `number` LIKE '%$rnumber%') OR (length(`number`) = '$lenNumber' && `number`LIKE '%$rnumber%')");
```

I tried many methods, but it was very slow in showing the results because I put the loop inside a loop to search for every number in the first loop

Comment: If you properly format your database query it becomes easier to read. That's useful for yourself, and for us.

Comment: For the pattern `XYZ44`, can X, Y or Z be a `4`? Similarly, For `123XX`, can X ever be `1`, `2` or `3`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas  Any number can be in X,Y,Z. It must not be among the numbers, meaning that 123XX can be any number except 1, 2, or 3

Comment: Huh?  Are you searching for something that matches all 6 patterns at the same time?  Or any one of the patterns?  In the second example, are 1 and 2 deliberately excluded by what X and Y can be?  (That did not seem to part of example 1.)  Are you looking for all numbers that match several patterns?  Let's see some complete examples -- a complete list of what restrictions exist, complete input, and complete output.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to look for `12344`, but some of the digits may be been redacted and replaced with a random capital letter in `XYZ`. For that, you can use a [regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like):

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(foo, '^[XYZ1][XYZ2][XYZ3][XYZ4][XYZ4]$')
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9phZ7EpRUS4FNRBZRdSYZa/2)

Comment: Then I didn't get requirements right. ‍♂️

Comment: Yes definitely not your fault for not abiding by someone else's assumption!